# Not performed .bashrc

Tags: linux, bash

I created the file `$HOME/.bashrc` (because it was not there), added some commands, and it does not run, that is not making all the settings that I made ​​there.
If you just type these commands in the console it works.

(Hosting is not mine)

Comment: Now that it seems to be a little translated with the last edit I'd say this is off-topic. Please have a look at the faq.

Comment: @dystroy please, help me if you may

Comment: You are really using bash as your default shell, did a relogin and parsing of a `~/.bashrc` is actually allowed by the administrators?

Comment: `man bash` and see Invocation section. All answers are there.

Comment: @honk I make changes to this file, but when I relogin - the team does not run out of file

Comment: @frops: There is no "team" in my `~/.bashrc` so I cannot say if they should run out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, bash won't read `.bashrc` if it is invoked as a *login shell*. (sometimes there's a system-wide workaround which hides this difference).

Add the following command in `$HOME/.bash_profile`:

```
. "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

Answer (score 1):

Belongs on superuser, but since it's a fairly easy thing:

BASH config files aren't automatically loaded when they're created/modified - you'll have to re-open your BASH session for them to be loaded, or run `source ~/.bashrc` to load the contents manually.

Comment: Was also guessing that, but in the comments OP said he tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Yeh just saw, Anton probably has it.